# DropdownButtonFormField value does change

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new Flutter and I am facing a problem and I have no idea why.
In Below code when choose value from DropDown it change value of "selectedMonths" But when i select DataRow it uses the default value "1". Please anyone help me with this.

```
vehicleFeeData(List<VehicleFee>? list) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: DataTable(
            showCheckboxColumn: true,
            headingRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.yellow[50]),
            border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.grey[200]!),
            columnSpacing: 20,
            columns: [
              DataColumn(label: Text('Plate Number')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Exp Date')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Monthly Fee')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Months')),
            ],
            rows: list!.map((fee) {

              int selectedMonths = 1; // This value

              return DataRow(
                  selected: vehiclesFee!.contains(fee),
                  onSelectChanged: (selected) {
                    if (vehiclesFee!.contains(fee)) {
                      state!(() {
                        print(selectedMonths);
                        vehiclesFee!.remove(fee);
                        vehiclesFeeTotal -=
                            (int.parse(fee.monthlyFee!) * selectedMonths);
                      });
                    } else {
                      state!(() {
                        print(selectedMonths);
                        vehiclesFee!.add(fee);
                        vehiclesFeeTotal +=
                            (int.parse(fee.monthlyFee!) * selectedMonths);
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(Text(fee.plateNumber!)),
                    DataCell(Text(fee.expDate!.toString().split('00').first)),
                    DataCell(Text(fee.monthlyFee!)),
                    DataCell(Container(
                      width: getProportionateScreenWidth(135),
                      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          state!(() {
                            selectedMonths = int.parse(value.toString());
                            print(selectedMonths);
                          });
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                          border: border,
                          enabledBorder: border,
                          errorBorder: border,
                          focusedBorder: border,
                          focusedErrorBorder: border,
                          hintText: "Select Months",
                        ),
                        items: popUpMenuItem,
                      ),
                    )),
                  ]);
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: The line `int selectedMonths = 1; ` is invoked *every single time you call vehicleFeeData()*.  Which is why it's always "1". You want to move "selectedMonths" *outside* of the function.  Suggestion: change it to a function parameter, e.g. `vehicleFeeData(List<VehicleFee>? list,int selectedMonths)  {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed to use `value` in dropdown

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          state!(() {
                            selectedMonths = int.parse(value.toString());
                            print(selectedMonths);
                          });
                        },
                        value: selectedMonths, // here need to change 
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                          border: border,
                          enabledBorder: border,
                          errorBorder: border,
                          focusedBorder: border,
                          focusedErrorBorder: border,
                          hintText: "Select Months",
                        ),
                        items: popUpMenuItem,
                      ),
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the mistake but that doesnot solve my problem. My problem was inside onChanged method I'm changing the selectedMonths value but when I select the DataRow it doesnot use the updated value, its use the value i initialized.

Comment: did you get the result ` print(selectedMonths);`

Comment: yes inside onChanged method it print updated value but inside onSelectChanged methods i used the initialized value

Comment: `state` referred to `setState`

Comment: yes as I am inside the bottomSheet so I used StatefulBuilder for updating its state

Comment: you need to update both ui like bottom sheet and main ui and try to pass the init value from main UI, I hope it would be solved your problem, and also use another setstate for the main ui

Comment: This problem is not related to main UI. Kindly check you email I have sent you the video of what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `int selectedMonths = 1;` outside the build method because when you call `!state` and the widget rebuild, `selectedMonths`'s value initializes to 1 again.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks buddy for your support.

Comment: No problem bro. You can accept the answer if it helped you.